# Cluster Groups based on overlap

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have the following data:

```
Group_id  item_id
     001      699
     001      533
     001      782

     002      699
     002      533
     002      782
     002      999
```

I want to assign `group_id` 001 and 002 in one cluster because they have a large overlap between `item_id`'s.

`Group_id` and `item_id` are just arbitrary numbers. So I am not sure if it makes sense to calculate distance between the `item_ids` numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned "hierarchical-clustering" in the tags I assume you want to use hierarchical clustering for this task.

### Distance Matrix

Hierarchical clustering can cluster groups based on their pairwise distance matrix. So what you need to do is to prepare a matrix of distances between all pairs of `group_id`s.

### Distance between each pair

In order to construct the distance matrix you need some way to measure the distances between each pair of `group_id`s. In your scenario you want to cluster groups based on the overlaps of their elements. One way to do this would be the *Jaccard similarity* which is an intersect over a union of elements.

With your example the Jaccard similarity between `group_id`s 001 and 002 would be computed like so:

1. Find the number of common elements: in your case - 3
2. Find the number of total unique elements in both groups: in your case - 4
3. Jaccard's similarity is 3/4

Note that Jaccard's similarity shows how similar two groups are. You will probably need to turn this into a matrix of distances. Since Jaccard's similarity ranges from 0 to 1 - you can transform them into distances by subtracting them from 1: **1 - Jaccard similarity**

### Hierarchical Clustering

Once you have the required distance matrix - you can continue with hierarchical clustering. There might be some parameters left to decide on (like a linkage function to use when combining two groups into a single cluster) but these are mostly problem dependant.